# Где взять описание таблицы cdr для asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Есть задача — построить отчет по звонкам. Есть таблица в MySQL. Как (где) узнать, какие в ней данные хранятся, какие статусы используются, как из этого выбрать нужное?

Подскажите, если кто сталкивался, есть подробное описание или, может, готовые запросы с описанием?

Конкретные вопросы, которые нужно задать таблице:

- время ожидания звонка в очереди
- время выхода из очереди без ответа

Comment: http://asterisk-support.ru/forum/topics/6011/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут более полная инфа если понадобиться
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5242894